# Threading behavior of methods of a class object declared as static member of another class

Tags: c#, oop, static-members, instance-methods

Recently a colleague of mine came up with a piece of code and asked my opinion regarding thread safety of the code. Below is an example that illustrates the same scenario as the code.

```
public class classA
{
   public int DoWorkA() 
   { 
       //some logic 
   }
}

public class classB
{
     public static classA objA = new classA();
}

public class classC
{
        int DoWorkC () 
        {

           return classB.objA.DoWorkA();

        }
}
```

Now if ClassB.objA.DoWorkA() is called simulatenously in different instances of different classes like ClassC, ClassD etc will there be any threading or 'overlap' issues ? Should objA be converted into an instance member ?

Answer (score 2):

Since `objA` is static there will be just a single instance of `classA`. That means all threads access the method `DoWorkA()` on the *same instance*, it does not mean however that the method call is thread-safe - that entirely depends on the implementation of `DoWorkA()`.

You will still need appropriate logic in `DoWorkA` to protect from problems that can arise with concurrent access, e.g. the use of locking or thread-safe collections etc.

Comment: Is it sufficient if DoWorkA() works only on local variables (in the scope of DoWorkA()) and not class members to make it thread safe? Would I still need to use locks ?

Answer (score 1):

> will there be any threading or 'overlap' issues

It depends on what `//some logic` does.  Each call will share the same instance, so `DoWorkA` would need to be thread safe in order for this to function correctly.

Any data used within `//some logic` needs proper synchronization for this to be safe.

Comment: There's also a potential race condition on the constructor of `classA`

Comment: @ConradFrix That constructor is guaranteed to only be called one time by the C# spec.  The only way there'd be a race condition would be if ClassA used shared/static data within its constructor, which itself wasn't safe.